# c# text from TextBox and draw line for Signature DGVPrinter in Windows form project

Tags: c#, printing, datagridview

I use DGVPrinter to printout Information from dataGridView. I want to have som text from TextBox and draw line for signature at the last page. Is that possible to create or draw line for signature at the end of the page of output from dataGridView.
This is code I use to printout the hole data from dataGridview, but I want to add more text from TextBox and draw a signature line

```
 DGVPrinter printer = new DGVPrinter();
            printer.Title = "Customer Report";

            printer.SubTitle = string.Format("Date: {0}", DateTime.Now.Date);
            printer.SubTitleFormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.LineLimit | StringFormatFlags.NoClip;
            printer.PageNumbers = true;
            printer.PageNumberInHeader = false;
            printer.PorportionalColumns = true;
            printer.HeaderCellAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
            printer.Footer = "Company name LTD";
            printer.FooterSpacing = 15;

            //  I want to have here like signature line  like 
            Signature:  _______________________________________________________
            and here som text from textbox .....

            printer.PrintDataGridView(dgvmonths);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is `DGVPrinter` the `Another DataGridView Printer` from CodeProject? https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18042/Another-DataGridView-Printer

Comment: @Smartis , Thank you for your response, I don't know but I Think it's almost the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution would be to extend the Page Footer:

```
...
printer.Footer = GetSignatureFooter("Company name LTD", "Thank you for your purchase");
printer.FooterSpacing = 15;
printer.PrintDataGridView(dgvmonths);
```

And the method for getting a footer with signature line:

```
private string GetSignatureFooter(string companyName, string additonalMessage)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.AppendLine("Signature: ".PadRight(60, '_'));
    sb.AppendLine();
    sb.AppendLine(additonalMessage);
    sb.AppendLine();
    sb.AppendLine(companyName);

    return sb.ToString();
}
```